# Can I use my xbox live account if I buy a new hard drive? Will my data also be there?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I'm thinking of buying a new Xbox 360 hard drive because I'm running out of space. Will I be able to log in to my xbox live account? And if so will all the saved data on the hard drive I have now with my xbox live account go with the new xbox hard drive I want to buy? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your xbox account signs in with Microsoft, directly. Replacing the hard drive will not effect this.

Naturally, any files on the hard drive you are removing will not be directly accessible, once the drive has been removed. You can consider two options to solve this problem:

- Using a USB flash drive formatted to accept Xbox 360 save data, you can transfer important saves to your backup USB, and transfer them on to the new hard drive.
- If you have Gold membership, you can use the cloud to simply store your saves online. These saves will be accessible from any drive or console, providing you have internet access, and Gold membership. This can also be used to transfer saves to the Xbox One, for use with backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to timelord64 is that on the Xbox one all saves will transfer with the account.

As far as achievements they will always travel with the gamer tag.

Buy a used data transfer cord from game stop then return it the same, next day and get your money back (which now they will give on a gift card I believe)